# И снова о "кофе"

Tags: этимология, морфология

Не будем сейчас обсуждать новояз, где "кофе" среднего рода. Все-таки, это слово мужского рода, но мне интересно, как вообще получилось и почему это слово, где, в общем-то, напрашивается средний род (по аналогии с "какао"), стало мужского рода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русский язык слово было заимствовано как слово среднего рода. Но параллельно существовала и форма кофей - мужского рода, т.к.  на согласный. Но склоняемый вариант не прижился, а род мужской остался.

Answer (score 1):

Вы напрасно называете современный средний род просто "новоязом". Словарями вариант уже фиксируется как разговорный.
Касательно происхождения слова. Я не слышал версии, что заимствовано оно было как слово среднего рода. Хотя готов допустить и такую версию, тем более, что в голландском слово именно среднего рода.

Зато знаю наверняка, что именно для придания слову внешних "аттрибутов" мужского рода и был изобретён вариант "кофий/кофей", ничем в иностранных языках не мотивированный. Поскольку форма "кофей" победила и при сильной фонетичекой мотивации французского сформировалась форма "кофе", которая большинством носителей ассоциируется уже со средним родом.

Comment: Интересно все же происходит. Некоторые слова как народ ни говорит, а словари фиксировать не торопятся даже как разговорный вариант. А вот слово кофе еще лет 20 назад в школьном учебнике 5 класса прямо справа в рамочке было дано с пометой мужской и средний род. Не прижилось! В следующие годы и до сих пор большая часть населения, активно употребляющая кофе, а не иные напитки,все-таки считает слово кофе мужского рода. Как там в  рекламе: если кофе вкусный, то это,конечно же,ОН, а если..., то ОНО. (А вот здесь бы смайлик не помешал...)

Answer (score 0):

ы напрасно называете современный средний род просто "новоязом". Словарями вариант уже фиксируется как разговорный. Касательно происхождения слова. Я не слышал версии, что заимствовано оно было как слово среднего рода. Хотя готов допустить и такую версию, тем более, что в голландском слово именно среднего рода.